# How can I find the interpolated position between 4 vertices in a fragment shader?

Tags: geometry, shader, directx-11, fragment-shader, geometry-shader

I'm creating a shader with SharpDX (DirectX11 in C#) that takes a **segment** (**2 points**) from the output of a *Vertex Shader* and then passes them to a *Geometry Shader*, which converts this **line** into a **rectangle** (**4 points**) and assigns the four corners a texture coordinate.

After that I want a *Fragment Shader* (which recieves the interpolated position and the interpolated texture coordinates) that checks the depth at the "spine of the rectangle" (that is, in the line that passes through the middle of the rectangle.

The problem is I don't know how to extract **the position of the corresponding fragment at the spine of the rectangle**. This happens because I have the texture coordinates interpolated, but I don't know how to use them to get the fragment I want, because the coordinate system of a) the texture and b) the position of my fragment in screen space are not the same.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: If you post your HLSL code for the shader I might be able to help a little bit better, but without code I can't do much. Also, as a nitpick, in DirectX, a fragment shader is called a pixel shader.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to extract the position of the corresponding fragment at the spine of rectangle. But for each fragment you have interpolated position (all, what you need to get it is to transmit it to fragment shader, and it will be interpolated for each fragment), and texture coordinates. Why can't you use it?  Why do you need to find exactly fragment coordinates?

Also, you can generate some additional data in geometry shader to do what you want.